# Printing a request scoped parameter using jstl

Tags: jstl, portlet, spring-el

I have 2 jsps. jsp1 goes to a portlet and portlet redirects to jsp2. jsp1 has a 'Finish' button that triggers the flow. jsp1 has also some other buttons.
In jsp1, I have:

```
<input type="submit" name="_finish" id="_finish" value="button.finish" />
```

in jsp2, I do: `<c:out value = "${param._finish}"/>`
But nothing prints on screen. However in portlet if I do:

```
request.getParameter("._finish"), I get a non-null value.
```

Why the value of the finish button does not come in jsp? I need to show a message in jsp2 if the Finish button was clicked.
I also tried:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope}" var="par">
<c:out value="${par.key} - ${par.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

But the _finish did not turn up in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Sorry for the trouble. There was a redirect happening in the portlet so the original request is not available